# Registering a static menu?

Tags: menus

I have a website with a very large sidebar menu that uses an accordion plugin to keep everything compact and organized. Unfortunately, my menu has grown so big that I am unable to save any new entries; my research shows that this is a known problem. Is there any way that I can create a static menu and register it so that it is recognized as a WordPress custom menu? I've been digging though codex, but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom widget that contained just your menu and then hardcode the menu in HTML...it's not a good solution, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was trying to avoid this since the plugin I was using has worked very well the purposes of my the website it is being used on. Seems like this might be my only solution though.

Comment: Try contacting your hosting and see if they can tell you what resource is holding you back on the default menu page and then see if they can give you a larger allocation of that. IMO the issue with large menus is a significant issue with wordpress that should have been addressed long ago...hopefully 3.4 will get it!

Comment: Well I'm using an unmanaged dedicated server, so they won't really help me in that regard. I've looked at resource usage during menu saves, and nothing peaks or looks out of the ordinary. Unfortunately the page just hands while trying to save and eventually throws Internal Error 500. 

Before this, I was getting php timeouts, but altering the max_execution_time fixed that. A few new menu items later and I'm stuck with this issue. Hopefully they do address is soon!

Comment: Have you increased your memory limit?

Comment: I just tried raising that up from 64 MB to 512 MB, but that didn't make any difference unfortunately. I really appreciate your suggestions, so if you have any other suspicions please let me know!